# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Open Data Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **May 20** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on May 20, users can [nominate themselves](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On May 27, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on June 4.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

How do you determine how many moderators a beta needs?

Comment: We like to have at least 3 moderators for a site whether it's a beta site or not. That gives us confidence that flags are handled and spam is removed even if one or two moderators take some time off. In this case, one of the moderators has not visited the site in the last 6 months or so. I don't have any immediate concern about the moderation on this site, but we're going to add one more too keep us up to 3 active moderators.